# (Re)drawing on a Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, swt

I'm about to code myself an analog clock in `SWT`. I managed to draw it for one point in time and everything works quite well until the point the control repaints itself.
It appears that the "old drawings" are persistent through the drawing events and i can't find a way to remove them. Ideal would be some sort of reference to the different shapes I'm drawing on the `Canvas` so that I can delete those individually but an approach to clear the complete canvas so that I can draw everything from scratch again would also be appreciated.

The onyl approach I have found is to dispose the current Canvas and create a new one on the exact same location instead but that seems like a huge waste of resources to me for something that simple...

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fill the `Canvas` with the background colour at the start of the paint event.

```
public void paintControl(PaintEvent event) {

  GC gc = event.gc;

  gc.setBackground(... background color ...);

  Rectangle fillRect = getClientArea();

  gc.fillRectangle(fillRect);

  ... continue drawing
}
```